# iOS 12+: Vue Mobile App - Crashes on Keyboard Enter Click

Tags: ios, cordova, vuejs2, vue-router, quasar-framework

We have a cross-platform mobile app built using Quasar Framework, Vue & Cordova.

On the login page, when the user attempts to log in to the app on an iOS device with version 12+, the app crashes when the user uses the keyboard "enter" key to submit their credentials.

Here is a simple view of the login form:
[Login Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFnLC.png)

The crash only occurs when they use the iOS keyboard. When the user uses the "Login" button on the login page, the app doesn't crash and it pushes the user to the home screen.

We have tested this on a device with iOS version 11.4 and the crash doesn't occur.

Here is a sample of my login page & script.

```js
import { required, email } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators';
import { filter } from 'quasar';

export default {
  name: 'PageLogin',
  data: function() {
    return {
      form: {
        username: '',
        password: ''
      },
      loggingIn: false
    };
  },
  validations: {
    form: {
      username: { required, email },
      password: { required }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      this.$v.form.$touch();

      // Only submit if there are no errors
      if (!this.$v.form.$error) {
        this.loggingIn = true;

        this.$store
          .dispatch('account/verifyUsername', this.form)
          .then(result => {
            //account/verifyUsername
            return this.$store.dispatch('account/login', this.form.password);
          })
          .then(result => { //account/login
            this.$router.push({ name: 'home' });
          })
          .catch(error => {})
          .finally(() => {
            this.loggingIn = false;
          });
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<template>
  <q-page>
    <form class="ad-form" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
      <q-field :error="$v.form.username.$error" error-label="Please enter a valid email address">
        <q-input type="email" v-model="form.username" float-label="Email" :error="$v.form.username.$error" @blur="$v.form.username.$touch">
          <q-autocomplete @search="onSearch" @selected="onItemSelected" :min-characters="0" value-field="email"/>
        </q-input>
      </q-field>
      <q-field :error="$v.form.password.$error" error-label="Please enter a password">
        <q-input type="password" v-model="form.password" float-label="Password" :error="$v.form.password.$error" @blur="$v.form.password.$touch"/>
      </q-field>
      <q-btn class="standalone" type="submit" color="primary" :loading="loggingIn" :disabled="$v.form.$invalid">Login
        <span slot="loading">
          <q-spinner class="on-left"/>Logging In
        </span>
      </q-btn>
      <q-btn class="standalone" type="button" flat color="secondary" :to="{ name: 'forgotPassword' }">Forgot your password?</q-btn>
    </form>
  </q-page>
</template>
```